# Getting Error in this C program for Romans to Integers using Structures.Can someone please look into this

Tags: c, structure

Getting Error in this C program for Romans to Integers using Structures.Can someone please look into this errors.
details about this program is to convert Roaman to integers without using arrays.

```
struct key_value
{
    char* key;
    int value;
};
int main(void) {
    //int number_of_keys = 7,
    int result = 0, x1, x2;
    //struct key_value *kv = malloc(sizeof(struct key_value) * number_of_keys);
    struct key_value kv[7];
    char input[50];
    kv[0].key = "I";
    kv[0].value = 1;
    kv[1].key = "V";
    kv[1].value = 5;
    kv[2].key = "X";
    kv[2].value = 10;
    kv[3].key = "L";
    kv[3].value = 50;
    kv[4].key = "C";
    kv[4].value = 100;
    kv[5].key = "D";
    kv[5].value = 500;
    kv[6].key = "M";
    kv[6].value = 1000;
    int i = 0;
    scanf("%s", input);
    while (input[i] != '\0') {
        /* Stop looping when we reach the null-character. */
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (input[i] == kv[j].key) {
                x1 = kv[j].value;
            }
        }
        if (i + 1 < strlen(input)) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
                if (input[i] == kv[k].key) {
                    x2 = kv[k].value;
                }
            }
            if (x1 >= x2) {
                result = result + x1;
            }
            else {
                result = result + x2 - x1;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            result = result + x1;
        }
    }
    printf("Result is %d", result);
    free(kv);
}
```

The errors are:

```
main.c:37:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
37 |      if(input[i]==kv[j].key){
  |                 ^~
main.c:43:17: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
43 |      if(input[i]==kv[k].key){
  |                 ^~
main.c:61:5: warning: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘kv’ [-Wfree-nonheap-object]
61 |     free(kv);
  |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `input[i]` is a character and `kv[j].key` is a string, or character pointer. You can't compare them directly. You might consider making `key` a `char` and using character literals with single quotes like `'I'` to initialize them. The `free(kv);` line you can remove since you did not use `malloc` to allocate the memory for it.

Comment: You should convert the assignments to `kv` elements into an initializer.  It isn't the cause of your problem, but it is better (much easier to read) if you do initialize the array.

Comment: Alternatively, without changing the structure, you could use `if (input[i] == kv[j].key[0])` — explicitly referencing the characters.

Comment: There are other problems to resolve too.  The code does not resolve "X" to 10; it goes into an infinite loop because you don't increment `i` in the final `else` clause.  But that's not sufficient either; entering "XX" goes into an infinite loop.  You have your work cut out to fix this algorithm.  I don't believe the data structure is sufficient to handle Roman numerals properly, but you can probably get it to work, more or less, most of the time.  Detecting erroneous input is going to be tricky.